# .net core 3.1 cert authentication returns 403 when deployed on Azure

Tags: azure, api, authentication, client-certificates, .net-core-3.1

I have followed this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to implement an authentication by certificat in my .net core 3.1 API. Everything works fine when I call my API on localhost, but I continously get an error **403** once the API is deployed on Azure.
I have no idea of what happens as there is no additional information on logs. I just don't understand what causes the **403**

As I understand, when I call my API routes I have to provide the certificate inside the "X-ARR-ClientCert" header, which is working fine locally, but seems not being interpreted on Azure.

Am I missing something ? Do I need to set a specific setting on my App Service ?

Comment: Did you try uploading your certificate which you have used for configuring the auth to the azure app service? If not, please follow this link and get it uploaded to your azure app service and check if it works after that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#upload-a-private-certificate

Comment: Hello !
Yes ! The certificate is uploaded on the API on Azure. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the article said, if the correct certificate is sent to the server, the data is returned. If `no certificate or the wrong certificate` is sent, an HTTP 403 status code is returned.

So, as Bhushan said, confirm your certificate has uploaded to azure app service.

When you enable mutual auth for your application, all paths under the root of your app will require a client certificate for access. Exclusion paths can be configured by selecting `Configuration` > `General Settings` and defining an exclusion path.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth).

Comment: Hello !
I have indeed saw this notice about the 403 error.
About the Incoming client certificates. When I enable it I also have a 403 error but caused by an exception. The exception is hired in the StringToByteArray method (from the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-certificate-authentication-in-azure-web-apps) with the wollowing message : Could not find any recognizable digits.

Comment: Can you also confirm your 'Incoming Client Certificates' settings of app service? Turn it ON and then try turning it OFF again and check if it helps?

Comment: The problem was in the method that convert the "X-ARR-ClientCert" header value to Certificate. In the doc I've followed, they convert it from Hexadecimal string, which works when you populate the header manually inside your Client App. 
In my case, my test were made via Swagger. So I had to select one of the certificates installed on my machine. And when you do so, the certificate (passed through the Header) is not encrypted within Hexadecimal string but Base64, and so should be done the conversion as described in Joey mentioned article. I've had to fix this to make it work !