# Certificate Authentication going through proxy .NET core 5 and 6 for API auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, x509certificate2

I have an application that authenticates wither certs and it is just fine in my local however when I move it to the server, it appears the application is going through proxy and I receive a forbidden error. 403.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(
        CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCertificate()
        .AddCertificateCache();

    // All other service configuration
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    // All other app configuration
}
```

I tried to hit the site with server name and I receive the response from the server and it is showing on the header Remote Address but when I use the host name's header contains proxies IP on Remote address.

meaning if I use the servername.com then it comes from server but when I use mysitesname.com then it is the proxies address.

I found this Microsoft document, I do not know which applies to me. [Microsoft's link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: As the article said, If the correct certificate is sent to the server, the data is returned. If no certificate or the wrong certificate is sent, an HTTP 403 status code is returned. You can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223876/net-core-3-1-cert-authentication-returns-403-when-deployed-on-azure).

Comment: In this case the correct Certificate is sent however proxy is over http and when you set the IIS to required you get a response of 403 from proxy basically.